# How do I get an image patch in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I put the background image, but do not know relative address. I create a folder 'image' in 'application/assets/' and put same image here, but in css file not recognize the address.

```
body {
    background-image:url('assets/image/images2.jpg');
}
```

Same problem when I want to attach css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/ipics.css">
```

Comment: Put your image css and javascript folders outside application folder

Comment: what is the path of your css folder? and are you writing the ody { background-image:url('assets/image/images2.jpg'); } in your css file or inline ?

Comment: If I put image  folders outside application folder work, but css is included in main.tpl. If I import from css folder don't work.

in main.tpl:

 <style>
          body
            {
               background-image:url('assets/image/images2.jpg');
            }
</style>

and when import from assets/css:

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/ipics.css">

ipics.css contains:

background-image:url('assets/image/images2.jpg');

dont't work

Comment: if i put  body
            {
             background-color: #234232;
/*             background-image:url("assets/image/brown.jpg");*/
            }                                                  background-color work.only image not work.with firebug appear: failed to load the given url.

Answer (score 1):

@globula_alba

Your best bet is to move your assets directory to the same level as applications & system, then reference all your images with base_url(), a Codeigniter function that matches your config.php base_url path.

So you will have:

```
base_url(). 'assets/images/myimage.gif';
```

or:

```
base_url('assets/images/myimage.gif');
```

(They both work the same way)

You can do the same thing for your css & javascript files